# Automatically fill SQL column with corresponding values

Tags: sql, function

I am new to SQL and I have a column of values "name" filled with fruit or vegetables name, I want to create a column "category" and fill it automatically with the corresponding name :

| name | category |
| --- | --- |
| orange | fruit |
| tomato | vegetable |
| avocado | vegetable |
| banana | fruit |
| orange | fruit |
| avocado | vegetable |

Which function should I use to achieve this when I use `ALTER TABLE` ?

Comment: _automatically_? How do you know that tomato isn't a fruit?

Comment: I don't have enough knowledge in biology to tell you if tomato is a fruit or a vegetable. But when I go to the supermarket and I weigh out some tomatoes, the weigh selection put tomato in the "vegetables" category. Might be cultural

Comment: Yeah, I think the point jarlh is making is that the database has no notion of "culture" either. Either you already have a table that links `tomato` to `vegetable` (in which case, just join on that, either in your queries themselves or by creating a view, do not store the data redundantly) or you do not (in which case, creating such a table manually will be necessary because the database can't conjure the data from nothing).

Comment: Ahh sorry I misunderstood, well, I wanted to create a list or whatsoever in the function to inform the database that "tomato, avocado" = vegetable, and "orange, banana" = fruit. The fact is that I don't know which SQL function can help me to fill it automatically after if I have like 500 orange and 300 avocados in the database.

Comment: Relational database engines typically have nothing along those lines; that's the domain of user-centric applications like Excel (which is very good at this sort of autocomplete stuff). If you have those 500 oranges and 300 avocados already you can of course extract the data (using `GROUP BY` / `DISTINCT`) and build the table based on that. Think tables and views, not functions.

Comment: It sounds like you want to add a field to an existing data table and to update that table so that the new field contains "fruit" or "vegetable". But then you say that you have "500 orange" and "300 avocados". This makes me think you should take a different approach. Are these 500 oranges really 500 sales of oranges? If so, don't update the `Sales` table with 500 sales to include "fruit", instead update the `StockedItems` table, so that the single stocked item "orange" is categorised as "fruit" (my table names are made up). Then `JOIN` tables in your query to pull from both tables at once.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, thank you for clarifying my implicit point. Now, is tomato fruit or vegetable? Yes, it is. http://www.growgardentomatoes.com/tomato-fruit-or-vegetable.html.

Answer (score -1):

From my point of view
First Alter your table using `ALTER TABLE` function then go for `GROUP BY`...